# Artificial intelligence application development in PHP

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence

I am new to AI development and looking for some guide line to start. I'm a php developer and if any one have experience AI developing in PHP, please help. Prefers AI related libraries and etc...

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: Entire university courses are taught on this subject; what kind of answer do you expect to get from a two-line question here?

Comment: @Daan - can't you see i mentioned here "I am new",

Comment: I am not talking about university course, i want to learn some AI theories and usage of them. I know PHP and need to learn AI concepts with PHP that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To develop AI applications, PHP seems not to be the best choice. It is a script language intended to create websites etc., not to, e.g., steer a robot. Of course you can use PHP to learn some concepts, but it makes sense to switch as soon as you want to create "serious" applications related to this topic.

To get into the topic, I recommend the Udacity course "Intro to Articial Intelligence", see https://www.udacity.com/course/cs271 - it is absolutly free to take this courses.

AI is not a simple topic, but it is very interesting. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Exactly I want integrate AI concept with web related application.Ex - seo acceleration application, or find nearest taxi etc.. And thank you to heads up.

Comment: I recommend to do the AI stuff by a backend application. E.g., a multi-threaded program running on your server and adding/updating results in your MySQL database. Afterwards this database is used by your PHP application to dynamically create the results page.

Especially if you are handling a lot of live data (e.g., taxi positions and routes), you will bring PHP to its knees.

Comment: I watched the videos and those are very basics but worked for me. Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't worry, the contents will become more challenging with later units. ;-)